# PagerAdapter instantiate item gets called for items on each scroll

Tags: java, android, xml, carousel, pager

I have an activity using the [Coverflow library](https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow) for Pagers. But I see a problem where everytime I scroll, `instantiateItem` is called again on all items in the limit (3 in this case since offscreen limit is set to 1). My pager only has 2 items, so all of them should be loaded in just one call to instantiateItem for each item (meaning 2 calls total regardless of how many times I scroll) instead of 2 calls on each scroll. This is making the scroll not smooth and laggy, which is not pretty at all. I tried to compare this with a setting a brand new project with pager and running that on my device, and that scrolls smoothly.

Any idea what I'm messing up?

The logs I see are (you can see the log lines in the adapter code below):

```
I/MyViewAdapter.class: [Wed Jan 08]>>>> Instantiate item in my view adapter called. Position: 0
I/MyViewAdapter.class: [Wed Jan 08]>>>> Instantiate item in my view adapter ended. Position: 0
I/MyViewAdapter.class: [Wed Jan 08]>>>> Instantiate item in my view adapter called. Position: 1
I/MyViewAdapter.class: [Wed Jan 08]>>>> Instantiate item in my view adapter ended. Position: 1
```

The XML is as follows:

MyActivity.xml

```xml
...
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <me.crosswall.lib.coverflow.core.PagerContainer
        android:id="@+id/pager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="275dp">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/overlap_pager"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:overScrollMode="never"/>

    </me.crosswall.lib.coverflow.core.PagerContainer>
</FrameLayout>
...
```

MyViewItem.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:civ_border_color="#fff"
                app:civ_border_width="2dip"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the activity, I'm loading the pager in `onCreate` like so:

MyActivity.java

```java
        PagerContainer container = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);
        container.setOverlapEnabled(true);
        pager = container.getViewPager();
        pager.setAdapter(new MyViewAdapter(MyActivity.this, models, firstPosition));
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

        // This is related to layout of the pager container: https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow
        CoverFlow coverFlow = new CoverFlow.Builder()
                .with(pager)
                .scale(0.3f)
                .pagerMargin(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pager_margin))
                .spaceSize(0f)
                .build();

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("onPageSelected: (prevPosition, position) = (%d, %d)", prevPosition, position));
                ImageView imageView = pager.findViewWithTag(pagerViewTagForPosition(position));
                imageView.setAlpha(1f);

                ImageView imageViewPrev;
                if (prevPosition == -1) {
                    imageViewPrev = pager.findViewWithTag(pagerViewTagForPosition(firstPosition));
                } else {
                    imageViewPrev = pager.findViewWithTag(pagerViewTagForPosition(prevPosition));
                }
                imageViewPrev.setAlpha(0.5f);
                prevPosition = position;
                // Update background and animation objects
            }
        });
```

And in the adapter:
MyViewAdapter.java

```java
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("[%s]>>>> Instantiate item in my view adapter called. Position: %d", new Date(), position));
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_view,null);
        final CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        final ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        circleImageView.setTag("tag_" + position);

        Picasso.get().load(models.get(position)).into(circleImageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, String.format("Failed to image. Error: %s", e));
                }
            });
        }

        container.addView(view);

        Log.i(TAG, String.format("[%s]>>>> Instantiate item in my view adapter ended. Position: %d", new Date(), position));
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the library I was using [was calling instantiate item for on page selection everytime](https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow/blob/master/coverflow/src/main/java/me/crosswall/lib/coverflow/core/PagerContainer.java#L155). So the solution was to just write my own PagerContainer that extends the one from library (because the library does make the view look pretty), and override the onPageSelected method:

```java
public class MyViewContainer extends PagerContainer {

    public MyViewContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyViewContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyViewContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //Disable clipping of children so non-selected pages are visible
        setClipChildren(false);

        //Child clipping doesn't work with hardware acceleration in Android 3.x/4.x
        //You need to set this value here if using hardware acceleration in an
        // application targeted at these releases.
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Override the page selected from the library since that one calls instantiate item again.
    }
}
```

Use your own container in the XML file as well. And that should be it.